# QGIS plugin - NameError: name 'iface' is not defined while importing class from other file

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, importerror

Here is my class

```
class aClassName():
    def __init__(self):
        #do something...

        iface.setActiveLayer(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('someName')[0])

        #do something
    ...
```

The class calls a number of methods from iface such as `setActiveLayer`, `.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()` etc in different functions. It runs properly when it is called in the same file.

But when I tried to use the class by importing it into another file:

```
from theClassFile import aClassName
```

The error message showed up and said :

> NameError: name 'iface' is not defined

even if adding `from qgis.utils import iface` to `theClassFile` with reference from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255803/how-do-i-fix-name-iface-is-not-defined).

I just began to use PyQGIS last month.

Here is my QGIS version:
[image]

Comment: Add `from qgis.utils import iface` to the import section of the file which contains `class aClassName`

Answer (score 1):

I tried in Python console, the following code works.

The content of the file `theClassFile.py` :

```
class aClassName():  
    def __init__(self):

        # Replace the name of your layer
        iface.setActiveLayer(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('alaska')[0])
        print('OK !')
```

The contents of the main script :

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import *

import sys 
# Path of theClassFile.py directory
sys.path.append(r'C:/Users/v.bre/Desktop/test/iface_double_scripts/')

from theClassFile import aClassName

aClassName()
```

I have two layers in my QGIS project. With this code, I change the active layer and I print a message. 
There are many bugs, if you modify theClassFile.py, QGIS will not take the changes into account. To solve this problem, sometimes think about restarting your QGIS.

Try this code and get back to me.

Comment: I tried the code by adding `data=None` at `__init__` and `.` before the imported file.  It shows `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__console__'`  pointing to the first line of the main script.

Comment: Maybe I made a mistake. Are you working in the Python console editor or are you in a plugin?

Comment: I'm working in Python console in QGIS

Comment: Sorry, my code is an exemple of plugin code.

Comment: I edited my code.

Comment: I added the new path as suggested, the error changed to `NameError: name 'processing' is not defined`. I tried to follow the solution [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279874/using-qgis3-processing-algorithms-from-standalone-pyqgis-scripts-outside-of-gui/279937), but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you try to just copy my code, you shouldn't get an error in the QGIS Python console because all QGIS modules are imported by default.

Comment: I pasted provided code and changed the layer name and file path to my own, but `NameError: name 'iface' is not defined` still appeared. p.s.  `aClassName` works fine when called within the `theClassFile.py`